# Is it possible to parallize exisiting binary code?

Tags: performance, assembly, parallel-processing, arm

I stumbled upon a proprietary library, performing highly parallelizeable operations. (Image Processing)

The device, which will use the library has 8 ARM cores, but the library occupies only one of them.

Compilers have the ability to automatically parallize loops. 
Is there tool, which can detect loops in binary code with it's dependencies and modify the code for parallization?

Comment: Well, the whole point of superscalar out-of-order processors is to find instruction-level parallelism in sequential code, but thread- or process-level parallelism is a different (*probably* much harder) problem.

Comment: Slice the image into 8 pieces, run 8 instances.

Comment: What @SevaAlekseyev says, or process 8 images simultaneously.

Comment: I can 't modify the input data, since the library communicates with the USB camera directly.

Comment: Can you somehow split acquisition and processing? The former can't be parallelized anyway.